# git mirror repository not showing commits and files

Tags: git, hash, show, mirror

I cloned one repository twice, one using normal mode, one using the `--mirror` flag:

```
$ git clone https://gitlab.com/abc.git
$ cp abc.git abc_normal.git
$ rm -rf abc.git

$ git clone --mirror https://gitlab.com/abc.git
$ cp abc.git abc_mirror.git
```

Why is it that I can see only some files in the mirror from the normal repo, when I can see them all in the normal repo?

```
abc_normal.git $ git show ${file_or_commit_hash}
<file/commit content>

abc_mirror.git $ git show ${file_or_commit_hash}
fatal: bad object ${file_hash}
```

I am able to see some files using the same commands above in both mirror and normal repo.

I thought I'd be able to see all the commits and file hashes in the mirror repo as well as the normal repo, but that doesn't seem to be the case. Thanks for any insight!

Answer (score 2):

The mirrored repo doesn't contain the working files of the original repo just the git files to reproduce the working files when needed.

The mirror is not for working on but should be cloned without the --mirror : "$ git clone <mirror repo path>

Can now see all working files in the new clone.

Commit logs should be visible in the mirror by doing a $ git log